# CSS in Django does not register to the console

Tags: css, django

My CSS files in Django are linked to my project, but the changes that I make in the CSS files do not register in the console. For example, when I change the color to my H1 and save it, nothing has been changed in my project. When I open the console in Chrome, its as if I had not made any changes.

Comment: If you're on Chrome try `ctrl+shift+r`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often this problem happens due to browser caching. Try reloading with STRG + F5 to ignore cached files. Otherwise you can disable the browser cache in  the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two things.
1. Restart the project again using the command `python manage.py runserver`
2. Run the command `python manage.py collectstatic` to load the static files(css/js/img etc.)